# Why is kubernetes reporting scheduling error because of Memory resource limits?

Tags: kubernetes

I'm trying to define a job with a resource limit, here is a basic pod definition:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
    name: busybox
    labels:
        app: busybox
spec:
    containers:
        - name: busybox
          image: busybox
          args: [/bin/sh, -c, 'sleep 600']
          resources:
            limits:
                memory: "1Gi"
                cpu: "1"
            requests:
                cpu: "0.1"
                memory: "400Mi"
    nodeSelector:
        gitlab: "true"
```

When declaring a job with a resource request of "300Mi" this works, but with a request of "400Mi" this fails with:

> 52m     29s     183 default-scheduler           Warning     FailedScheduling    No nodes are available that match all of the following predicates:: Insufficient memory (3), MatchNodeSelector (2).

Getting the relevant information from `kubectl describe node <relevant node>` shows me the following under resources:

> Capacity:
>    cpu:     2
>    memory:  2052872Ki
>    pods:        110
>   Allocatable:
>    cpu:     2
>    memory:  1950472Ki
>    pods:        110

Further down, past the system info I get the following:

> ```
> Allocated resources:
>   (Total limits may be over 100 percent, i.e., overcommitted.)
>   CPU Requests    CPU Limits  Memory Requests Memory Limits
>   ------------    ----------  --------------- -------------
>   150m (7%)   1 (50%)     12Mi (0%)   128Mi (6%)
> Events:       <none>
> ```

Now, *why* is this job refusing to schedule with a request of 400Mi, but works fine when requesting 300Mi?  Nothing I add or subtract can show me that the 2GiB accessible memory ( as per "Allocatable" above)  would cause this job to not schedule.

I only have a single container (busybox for demo sake).

There is no resource quota for the namespace.

Restarting the apiserver appears to allow pods to schedule, but only for a while.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer turns out to be:

**Because I was using a too old version of etcd**

Specifically, upgrading to version 3.1.7 or later solved the problem.